# Taking out only paragraph value in plain form in python

Tags: python

Please can anybody help me to find data in

tag in python in plain form,I have explained the question

> Zale\u2019s largest shareholder, TIG, is highlighting Bank of
>   America\u2019s conflict of interest in a sale to Signet Jewelers. That
>   and other factors may lead shareholders to vote down the deal, Steven
>   M. Davidoff writes in the Deal Professor.  Read more…</a></p>\n</div>\n</article>"}

I want output like

> Zale largest shareholder, TIG, is highlighting Bank of America
>   conflict of interest in a sale to Signet Jewelers. That and other
>   factors may lead shareholders to vote down the deal, Steven M.
>   Davidoff writes in the Deal Professor.

Code for this

```
import urllib2
import re
response = urllib2.urlopen('http:')
print "Response:", response
regex = '<div class=\"entry-content\">(.*?)</div>'
pattern =re.compile(regex)
# Get all data
html = response.read()
splitsource = re.findall(pattern,html)
print "this is the",splitsource
```

But I m getting splitsource empty

```
splisource = []
```

Please help

Comment: check the value of `html`

Comment: this is returning the whole source code for the specified url not the output for which i m looking

Answer (score 0):

This will get the text from the paragraphs in the html:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715844/taking-out-only-paragraph-value-in-plain-form-in-python"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for t in soup.find_all("p"):
    print t.getText()
```

Have a look at the [beautifulsoup docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: thanx this works; but it is giving me too many\t\n..... in my plaintext,Is there any other code without using Beautifulsoup,simply using regular expression or modifying in my code.